# Is it possible to use Log In With PayPal (previously PayPal Access) in the Sandbox environment?

Tags: authentication, paypal, paypal-sandbox

The [Log In with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/loginwithpaypal/gs_loginwithpaypal/) endpoints work (adding 'www.sandbox' to the start of URLs) e.g. https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/loginauth?execution=e3s2 but I cannot find anywhere to get Sandbox `client_id` and `client_secret` credentials that work with it.

I've tried using my real credentials (which you get at http://devportal.x.com) and they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Login With PayPal" when working with the Sandbox.  You can get the credentials by selecting “Login with PayPal” option on the “Create Account” form when creating a business account. The credentials generated will appear in the “API Credentials” section of the profile.